# Construct insert query based on columns from another table variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

apologies if this has been asked but my actual question is actually terribly difficult to query using search.

I have a table variable that I've created which constains the IDs, column names and table names of other tables such that an example row consists of

**ID, Column, Table**

2, AssetName, dbo.Asset

I now wish to insert into another table variable the results of a query which is composed of that row, for eg:

insert into @table2
..
'select AssetName from dbo.Asset' [the results, specifically the AssetName column from the Asset table - perhaps 10 rows worth of data]

Please let me know how best to approach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to do that dynamically. For example, something like (untested):

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @SQL = N'INSERT INTO @Table2 SELECT ' + QUOTENAME(Column) + N' FROM ' + QUOTENAME(Table)
FROM   @Table1

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```

I'm not entirely sure if you don't need a global table variable for that (`@@Table2`).

Comment: Or use a temp table that is declared prior to the dynamic sql.

Comment: I would note that you had to declare the table variable within the dynamic sql code for it to be recognised but regardless, in spite of my ignorance in this area this clearly seems like the way.